# Fabricjs curved text bad coords

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have problem with framework `fabric.curvedText.js`. I got example from this site https://github.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText

I'm add one line 'angle: 60'. Only when angle is 0 coords are good. `SetCoords()` doesn't help. Below is an example.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y10vjagy/6/

How fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start rendering with angle: 0;

Change curved text angle after load, in that way you are rotating text and wrapping frame simultaneous (I think this is a bug what you encountered here), anyhow if you need to render at loading with some angle, change angle to desired one after object rendering.

```
// where obj is curved text object
if(obj){
            obj.set($(this).("angle"), 60); 
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7wLnz6pq/

**Update:**

```
$('#radius, #spacing, #fill').change(function(){
        var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if(obj){
            var angle = obj.get('angle');
            obj.set('angle', 0);
            obj.set($(this).attr('id'),$(this).val()); 
            obj.set('angle', angle);
        }
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
    $('#angle').change(function(){
        var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if(obj){
            obj.set($(this).attr('id'),$(this).val()); 
        }
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
```

Set angle to 0 when radius and spacing is changed http://jsfiddle.net/7wLnz6pq/1/

Comment: In your example when I set angle in control range to e.g. 180 and then change radius or spacing, coords are broke down. If i use rotating corner on canvas and then change radius or spacing everything is ok. Problem is with set() method. I trying use setAngle() but effect was the same.

Comment: Ok, I will add an update for this just for you, because to much words won't help